# iOS Universal Links fails to Open the App

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, ios-universal-links

4 months ago we used to have Universal Links enabled and it was all good. But we have decided to black-list paths instead of white-listing them. So we have replace the paths with `NOT /path/*`. After deploying the files to our domains and subdomain. It seems that the iOS is not associating the domains at all.

Our file looks like this

```
{
"applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
        {
            "appID": "1242141.com.app.dev",
            "paths": [
                "NOT /path1/*",
                "NOT /path2/*",
                "NOT /path3/*",
                "NOT /path4/*",
                "NOT /path5/*",
                "NOT /path6/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "appID": "1231411.com.app.production",
            ......
```

Another question, if you have app extensions (say a rich push service) do you need to enable Associated Domains for them as well or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to add the paths which are allowed

Use something like:

```
{
    "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "1242141.com.app.dev",
        "paths": [
            "*",
            "NOT /path1/*",
            "NOT /path2/*",
            "NOT /path3/*",
            "NOT /path4/*",
            "NOT /path5/*",
            "NOT /path6/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: That surely was the missing part. Thank you!